# How to create composite slot types in an alexa skill?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Is there a way to create composite slot types in Alexa skill? A composite slot type (entity) can be explained as if there are 3 slot types as slotType1, slotType2 and slotType3, values of slotType3 are created combining values of slotType1 and slotType2.

Comment: Can't you just capture utterances like: "give me {slot1} {slot2}" and then join them in the backend to construct your type 3?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you won't be able to do this in the Alexa Console.

And I don't think you'll be able to do it the way you are hoping. But the closest solution I can think of is to use [Alexa Skills Management API (SMAPI)](https://developer.amazon.com/alexa-skills-kit/smapi) or [Alexa Skills Kit Command Line Interface (CLI)](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/ask-cli-intro.html) to update the interaction model programmatically.

That way you could retrieve the current interaction model, parse the slotTypes, and combine slotTypes 1 and 2 values into slotType 3, then update the interaction model.

Of course, you can only do that with custom slotTypes. So you won't be able to do this with any built-in slotTypes.